# invalid argument when imploding in php

Tags: php, arrays

Im getting invalid argument error when running the following code. Im trying to change the value of a line in the `$info` array, then implode it, implode its parent array, and then save the whole shebang back to whence it came.

```
$rowpre = $_GET['row'];
$newfieldvalue = $_GET['nfv'];
$row = --$rowpre;
$data = file_get_contents("temp.php");
$csvpre = explode("###", $data);
$i = 0;
    foreach ( $csvpre AS $key => $value){
        $i++;
        if($i = $row){
            $info = explode("%%", $value);
            $info[$target] = $newfieldvalue;

            $presave = implode("%%", $info);    
        }           
    }


$save = implode("###", $presave);
$fh = fopen("temp.php", 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $save);
fclose($fh);
```

**update below**

```
$rowpre = $_GET['row'];
$newfieldvalue = $_GET['nfv'];
$target = $_GET['target'];
$row = --$rowpre;
$data = file_get_contents("temp.php");
$csvpre = explode("###", $data);
$i = 0;
    foreach ( $csvpre AS $key => $value){
        $i++;
        if($i == $row){
            $info = explode("%%", $value);
            $info[$target] = $newfieldvalue;

            $csvpre[$key] = implode("%%", $info);  
        }           
    }


$save = implode("###", $csvpre);
$fh = fopen("temp.php", 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $save);
fclose($fh);
```

Target is the field within the selected Row that i wish to update with the newfieldvalue data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $save = implode("###", $presave);

At that point, `$presave` is a string, and should be an array to work with implode. Create an array where you push the $presave-values, and implode that one.

Answer (score 1):

`$presave` contains the last processed line (i.e. a string) and `implode` expects an array. To store the line back in the original array, change:

```
$presave = implode("%%", $info);
```

to:

```
$csvpre[$key] = implode("%%", $info);
```

And to convert the whole CSV array into a string, change:

```
$save = implode("###", $presave);
```

to:

```
$save = implode("###", $csvpre);
```

And one more problem:

```
if($i = $row){
```

should be:

```
if($i == $row){
```

because you want to compare the variables, not assign `$i`.

Comment: Its running without error, but doesnt seem to be changing the line in the array at $info[$target] = $newfieldvalue;

Comment: Where is defined `$target`. Try to `print_r` the `$csvpre` array in the loop to see if you are actually modifying it.